# When reassigning color to pixels, all color is black

Tags: java, image, colors

Simplified code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {

            if (complex.getInfinite()) {
                Color newcol = new Color(100, 0, 0);
                img.setRGB(i, j, newcol.getRGB());
            }
            if (complex.getInfinite() == false) {
                Color newcol = new Color(0, 0, 100);
                img.setRGB(i, j, newcol.getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    saveImage(img, new File("Julia.jpg"));
}
```

My problem is that when I run the program, Julia.jpg is a completely black image.
I have played around with the amount of pixels I color and only the pixels I am coloring turn black.

I was wondering if the issue was that when I generated the image I gave it the wrong type.

Comment: Why are you checking `if (complex.getInfinite())` followed by `if (complex.getInfinite() == false)`?

Comment: And what is `complex`?

Comment: complex is an instance of class Complex for complex numbers. The idea is to create an image for julia fractals where the x dimension is real number values and the y dimension is the imaginary element. If the coordinate inputted spirals off into infinity (when plugged into f(z) = z^2 + c for 255 iterations) then getInfinity() returns True.

Comment: Can you show some of the relevant 'Complex' code? Your included code should be minimal, but still complete. It's hard to see why all your pixels are black given the current code.

Comment: I "suspect" that neither of your `if` conditions are been met

Comment: I pass Creal, Cimag, realMin, realMax, imagMin, imagMax, real and imag as parameters to complex. I try to do all of the work in a single method check(). My logic is using mainly factorial methods.

Comment: @CodingWill Include the relevant code in your question!

Comment: Done. Still getting used to the website.

Comment: @CodingWill Is your `Complex` class very long? Can you include the entire class if it's not?

Comment: class Complex {
    double Creal, Cimag;
    double realMin, realMax;
    double imagMin, imagMax;
    double real, imag;
    boolean infinite = false;
    double forReal, forImag;

Comment: I couldn't get the comment of code onto the question, but it is right above the Complex constructor.

Comment: Try changing `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR`

Comment: Woot! That did the trick Gosu! Thank you very much.

Comment: @CodingWill Seriously? Okay, gonna add that as an answer then lol. I was reading the BufferedImage documentation and thought that it might have something to do with that..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

to

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
```

More details: [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_BGR)